# Sorting nested hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, inject

Provided the following ruby hash:

```
{
    cat: {
        1: 2,
        2: 10,
        3: 11,
        4: 1
    },
    wings: {
        1: 3,
        2: 5,
        3: 7,
        4: 7
    },
    grimace: {
        1: 4,
        2: 5,
        3: 5,
        4: 1
    },
    stubborn: {
        1: 5,
        2: 3,
        3: 7,
        4: 5
    }
}
```

How can I sort the hash by the sum of 'leaf' excluding "4", for instance the value to compare for "cat" would be (2 + 10 + 11) = 23, the value for "wings" would be (3 + 5 + 7) = 15 so if I was comparing just those two they would be in the correct order, highest sum on top.

It is safe to assume that it will ALWAYS be {1: value, 2: value, 3: value, 4: value} as those are keys for constants I have defined.

It is also safe to assume that I will only ever want to exclude the key "4", and always use the keys "1", "2", and "3"

Based on Jordan's suggestion I got this to work:

```
  tag_hash = tag_hash.sort_by do |h| 
    h[1].inject(0) do |sum, n| 
      n[0] == 4 ? sum : sum + (n[1] || 0)
    end
  end
```

The results seem a bit off but it appears to be my code, once I confirm that I'll accept the answer, thanks Jordan!

I've updated my solution to use Wayne Conrad's idea, see my comment on his answer - Is it possible that its not carrying everything when it sorts, I linked to an image in my comment that shows the result of the actual sort in graph form.. seems odd to me..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
tag_hash = tag_hash.sort_by do |_, leaf|
  leaf.reject do |key, _|
    key == 4
  end.collect(&:last).inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: +1, nice solution. I don't know why so many people refuse to use destructuring bind, @Jordan's solution for example is hideously ugly because of not using it. One suggestion: replace the outer `key` parameter with `_` to make it clear you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: This accomplished the same thing (but is more aesthetically pleasing), but i graphed the results from my sort, andthis is what it came out with http://imgur.com/NFxfM it seems odd.. it IS sorted.. but it almost looks like its not sorted quite enough..

Comment: Jörg: I agree that my solution is less pretty than Wayne's, but doing one inject struck me as more efficient than chaining reject->collect->inject. I prefer to iterate over a data structure fewer times when possible.

Comment: @Jordan, I agree -- there is a tension between aesthetics and performance.  @Jörg W Mittag, what is "destructuring bind?"  It sounds neat.  @Rabbott, that's odd.  Are you graphing exactly the same data as is being sorted?

Comment: @Wayne: destructuring bind (aka destructuring assignment) is a limited form of pattern matching, where you have some complex data structure on the right side of an assignment and a pattern on the left, and the language takes apart the structure of the data structure and binds (assigns) values from *inside* the data structure to variables on the left. Ruby supports destructuring only for arrays, like this: `a, (b, c, *d), e, *f = [1, [2, 3, 4, 5], 6, 7, 8] # => a=1 b=2 c=3 d=[4, 5] e=6 f=[7, 8]` You use it to seperate out key and value in the `[key, value]` array that Ruby passes you.

Comment: @Wayne: it not only works for assignments, but also for binding argumemnts in methods and blocks. In your example, you use `hsh.sort_by do |k, v| ... end` instead of `hsh.sort_by do |el| ... end`, which allows you to refer to the key and value as `k` and `v` instead of `el.first` and `el.last` (or even `el[0]` and `el[1]`) which is much less readable unless you happen to memorize which order Ruby passes them in. In @Jordan's code, using `inject do |sum, (k, v)| k == 4 ? sum : sum+v end` would be easier to read. Actually, I would use a guard clause and do `next sum if k == 4; sum+v` instead.

Comment: @Jörg, a perfect explanation.  I never knew there was such a fancy name for it, or that it did as much as in your example.  Thanks!

Comment: I've learned quite a bit from this question, thanks to all who contributed and commented!

Answer (score 2):

```
my_hash.sort_by do |_, h|
  h.inject(0) do |sum, n|
    # only add to the sum if the key isn't '4'
    n[0] == 4 ? sum : (sum + n[1])
  end
end
```

This can, of course, be shortened to a hideously unreadable one-liner:

```
my_hash.sort_by {|k,h| h.inject(0) {|sum,n| n[0] == 4 ? sum : (sum + n[1]) } }
```

Comment: Yea this isn't deep enough, looks like it needs to go one level deeper for the addition..

Answer (score 0):

This

```
puts a.sort_by { |k, v| -v.values[0..-1].inject(&:+) }
```

produces the following output, was this what you wanted?

```
cat
{1=>2, 2=>10, 3=>11, 4=>1}
wings
{1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>7, 4=>7}
stubborn
{1=>5, 2=>3, 3=>7, 4=>5}
grimace
{1=>4, 2=>5, 3=>5, 4=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
x.sort_by{ |_,h| h.values.take(3).inject(:+) }
```

This assumes that the subhashes are sorted (the first three entries are the entries you want to sum up).

When you use ActiveSupport you could do this:

```
x.sort_by{ |_,h| h.values.take(3).sum }
```

or

```
x.sort_by{ |_,h| h.slice(1,2,3).values.sum }
```

Hash#slice returns a hash that contains only the keys passed to slice. Array#take returns an array containing the first n entries of the source array.

(Ruby 1.9.1 required i think)